# Firebase OTP credential verify doesn't work with phone number

Tags: unity, firebase

I have 2 functions, the first function works correctly. The second one, when I put the OTP and want to verify the code from my SMS it doesn't work, it only creates a user in my Firebase database but it won't show me the debug text and run the other codes like changing the scene.

```
public void SendOTP()
{
   
    provider = PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(auth);
    
    provider.VerifyPhoneNumber(countryCode.text + phoneNumber.text, phoneAuthTimeoutMs, null,
      verificationCompleted: (credential) => {
          // Auto-sms-retrieval or instant validation has succeeded (Android only).
          // There is no need to input the verification code.
          // `credential` can be used instead of calling GetCredential().
      },
      verificationFailed: (error) => {
          // The verification code was not sent.
          // `error` contains a human readable explanation of the problem.
      },
      codeSent: (id, token) => {
          verificationId = id;
          debug.text = "code sent";
          // Verification code was successfully sent via SMS.
          // `id` contains the verification id that will need to passed in with
          // the code from the user when calling GetCredential().
          // `token` can be used if the user requests the code be sent again, to
          // tie the two requests together.
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeOut: (id) => {
          // Called when the auto-sms-retrieval has timed out, based on the given
          // timeout parameter.
          // `id` contains the verification id of the request that timed out.
      });
}

public void VerifyOTP()
{
    
    Credential credential = provider.GetCredential(verificationId, otp.text);

    auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
        debug.text = ("User signed in successfully");
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            debug.text = ("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " +
                           task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
        debug.text = ("User signed in successfully22");
        // This should display the phone number.
        //debug.text = ("Phone number: " + newUser.PhoneNumber);
        // The phone number providerID is 'phone'.
       // debug.text = ("Phone provider ID: " + newUser.ProviderId);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
    });
}
```

Comment: but the posted code does not create a db user, are you sure you are calling the correct function?

Comment: it's the default user's database of firebase
FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;